# Any idea about QQ API (Chinese facebook,twitter)?

Tags: api, status, microblogging

Is there any API for QQ services (www.qq.com)? Or any developer program? Is there any way to integrate their services in third party apps? I am interested in their microblog, photo album and status services. I translated and searched but couldn't dig far enough. Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems all the info is at http://open.qq.com, which will lead you to pages like http://open.t.qq.com/apps_welcome.php (for microblogging), http://opensns.qq.com/share/ (for sharing), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Tencent (aka Tencent QQ) has a popular application called "wechat".

They have an ios api you can use here:
http://dev.wechatapp.com/document/sdk-en/ios/protocol_w_x_api_delegate-p.html

Comment: Looks like the wechat dev is only for posting into the stream rather than interacting with it.